# Custom SurfaceView crashing app

Tags: android, android-fragments, surfaceview

I have a custom `SurfaceView` I want to display displaying in a `Fragment`, but the moment I add it, the app crashes.

The custom `SurfaceView` code is as follow:

```
public class CameraFocusIndacatorSurfaceView extends SurfaceView implements Runnable {

    private final Paint paint;
    private final SurfaceHolder mHolder;
    private final Context context;

    @Override
    public void run(){}

    public CameraFocusIndacatorSurfaceView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    mHolder = getHolder();
    this.context = context;
    paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    init();
}           

    private void init(){
        mHolder.setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSPARENT);
        paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        //do some stuff
    }
}
```

The app crashes as soon as this line is called in the `Fragment` that the `SurfaceView` resides in:

`View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_attachment_upload_camera, container, false);`

And here is the view stack for the `Fragment`:

[image]

Is the constructor not being picked up, or what?

Comment: To be inflated from a layout, any custom `View` subclass must have a `public` constructor that takes exactly a `Context` and an `AttributeSet`. `AttachmentUploadCameraFragment` is not `Context`, so no suitable constructor is found.

Comment: I see, but it seems the fragment is not passing in the Context, I tried changing it to the way it's done in the link you've provided an d it's still not working - I updated my post

Comment: Fixed it, just needed to change the second overload constructor to have the same signature.

Comment: Check my comment, and that link, again. You're missing the `AttributeSet` parameter.

Comment: Thank you - It is up and running now